# power automate to change date format in one column in a table created from xlsx

Tags: power-automate

can anyone suggest be if there is any other option to do this have  its saying' failed: 'In function 'formatdatetime', the value provided for date time string '' was not valid. The datetime string must match ISO 8601 format.'.

```
"ETA": "2022-11-16T10:03:00.000Z",
```

-- desired output i need

```
"ETA" : "16-11-2022  10:03:00"
```

I did use the function

```
formatdatetime(item()?['ETA'], 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

[image]

[image]

-- desired output i need

```
"ETA" : "16-11-2022  10:03:00"
```

then I need to save the output in csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like on of your ETA rows in the Table is empty.

You could add error handling to your expression. Try something like below:

```
if(empty(item()?['ETA']), '', formatdatetime(item()?['ETA'], 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'))
```

Comment: Thanks for sorting this, now its working as expected